"date.struct" not converting into date in Grails 6.2
I have a hidden field in a .gsp file as shown below:
<g:hiddenField value="date.struct" name="effectiveDate">
In the controller, we check the value as follows:
if(params["effectiveDate"])  
{     
   // true part 
}else {
    // else part
}
In the controller, params["effectiveDate"] is coming through as a string and is not being automatically converted into a date. This functionality worked in Grails 3, but it is not working in Grails 6. It should work the same way it did in Grails 3.
